# Starting the server makes my application hang

Tags: c#

So in the last 4 days, I've tested with TCPListener and TCPClient. I've Easily Created a Standalone Server/Listener and a Standalone Sender/Client. Now I'm trying to do it all in one application, but when I try to start the server the entire application hangs. I don't understand why as it is almost the same code as when I did in different applications.

I have tried multiple variations of it and watched multiple Tutorials, but as its actually the Same code I already used I don't know what's happening.

The problem happens once I click the start button triggering the StartButton_Click method

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.IO;

namespace ChatTest2
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private TcpClient client;
        public StreamReader STR;
        public StreamWriter STW;
        public string recieve;
        public String TextToSend;
        public Form1()

        {
            InitializeComponent();

            IPAddress[] localIP = Dns.GetHostAddresses(Dns.GetHostName());

            foreach (IPAddress address in localIP)
            {
                if (address.AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetwork)
                {
                    ServerIPtextBox.Text = address.ToString();
                }
            }

        }

        private void StartButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            TcpListener listener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, int.Parse(ServerPorttextBox.Text));
            listener.Start();
            client = listener.AcceptTcpClient();
            STR = new StreamReader(client.GetStream());
            STW = new StreamWriter(client.GetStream());
            STW.AutoFlush = true;

            backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
            backgroundWorker2.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;

        }

        private void ConnectButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            client = new TcpClient();
            IPEndPoint IpEnd = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(ClientIPtextBox.Text), int.Parse(ClientPorttextBox.Text));

            try
            {
                client.Connect(IpEnd);

                if (client.Connected)
                {
                    ChatScreentextBox.AppendText("Connected to server" + "\n");
                    STW = new StreamWriter(client.GetStream());
                    STR = new StreamReader(client.GetStream());
                    STW.AutoFlush = true;
                    backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
                    backgroundWorker2.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;

                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString());
            }
        }

        private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            while (client.Connected)
            {
                try
                {
                    recieve = STR.ReadLine();
                    this.ChatScreentextBox.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate ()
                    {
                        ChatScreentextBox.AppendText("You:" + recieve + "\n");
                    }));
                    recieve = "";
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString());
                }
            }
        }

        private void backgroundWorker2_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            if (client.Connected)
            {
                STW.WriteLine(TextToSend);
                this.ChatScreentextBox.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate ()
                {
                    ChatScreentextBox.AppendText("Me:" + TextToSend + "\n");
                }));
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Sending failed");
            }
            backgroundWorker2.CancelAsync();
        }

        private void SendButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (MessagetextBox.Text != "")
            {
                TextToSend = MessagetextBox.Text;
                backgroundWorker2.RunWorkerAsync();
            }
            MessagetextBox.Text = "";

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: _And you get no errors?_

Comment: No it justs "lags" nothing is acceptable anymore its just a crash till i stop the Programm

Comment: Lagging and crashing aren't the same thing, could you define lagging as well? Does the GUI stop responding? Also, why are you running backgroundWorker1 in both methods but telling backgroundWorker2 that cancellation is supported?

Comment: Maybe a "no response from programm" is a better explaination,when i click on the startserver button, nothing is working the programm is "open" but i cant click anything i cant reach it, if i tab out of it i cant even open it anymore. 
Sry english isnt my main language its hard for me to explain but that basicly should be it

ive been watching youtube Tutorials after, ive seen my server not working anymore, and that is basicly a complete replica of the code of his tutorial. And it STILL doesnt work, even when it should be working as the comment section of the Video says.

Comment: "crash" usually means an exception. Could you share any details of that?

Comment: The button is handled on the UI thread, and `client = listener.AcceptTcpClient();` is blocking. This means that the UI will block until a connection is accepted.

Comment: Is the following instruction failing : listener.Start()?  If so the port number you are using is already used or being blocked.  What port number are you using?  To see if port is already in use from cmd.exe type following : >Netstat -a

Comment: @John That was the Solution it wasnt a Crash u actually got it right, it waiting till something is connected Thanks ! Now i actually can go back to my own Programm.

I think its closeable is there a command for it?
#Close

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
client = listener.AcceptTcpClient();
```

This line is blocking your UI Thread.

I would try to use async and await.

```
private async void StartButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TcpListener listener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, int.Parse(ServerPorttextBox.Text));
        listener.Start();
        client = await listener.AcceptTcpClientAsync();
        STR = new StreamReader(client.GetStream());
        STW = new StreamWriter(client.GetStream());
        STW.AutoFlush = true;

        backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
        backgroundWorker2.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;

    }
```

I hope it helps you.